# Piping cat into wall (e.g. cat | wall)

Tags: pipe, cat, echo, stdout, wall

Why does `echo foo | wall` work but `cat | wall` not work? In the latter case, I enter a couple lines into cat, and in theory they should pipe to wall; however, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wall` doesn't send each line of its input as a separate message. It collects the entire input so that it can send a single `Broadcast Message from ...` heading before the message, rather than sending a separate heading for each line.

If you want to process the input a line at a time, you can insert a loop between `cat` and `wall`:

```
cat |while read -r line; do wall <<<"$line"; done
```

Comment: `cat` not needed here.

Comment: @Kusalananda Just trying to match the question. I assume that the real application will be piping something else and this is a placeholder.